# How should the builders be exposed?

Tags: java, builder

Let's say I have a builder class, which is to build an Item object that belongs to other package.

```
package mypackage;

import otherpackage.Item;

public class ItemBuilder {

    private Material material;
    private boolean unbreakable;

    public ItemBuilder setMaterial(Material material) {
        this.material = material;
        return this;
    }

    public ItemBuilder setUnbreakable(boolean unbreakable) {
        this.unbreakable = unbreakable;
        return this;
    }

    public Item build() {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.material = material;
        item.unbreakable = unbreakable; // Just example, the actual process is much complex than this one
        return item;
    }

}
```

I also have another utility class, Items, which is like this:

```
package mypackage;

import otherpackage.Item;

public final class Items {

    private Items() {
    }

    public static boolean checkOwner(Item item, String owner) { // Again, just example
        return item.owner.equals(owner);
    }

}
```

My package is an utility package to the other package. Therefore I want to make the utilities provided (such as ItemBuilder) accessible to developers as easy as possible.

Now I have two way to expose the class, one is, just **let developers instantiates it**.

```
new ItemBuilder().setMaterial(...).setUnbreakable(...).build();
```

Which is same as StringBuilder.

The other is to **make the ItemBuilder constructor package-local**, and edit the Items class to:

```
package mypackage;

import otherpackage.Item;

public final class Items {

    private Items() {
    }

    public static boolean checkOwner(Item item, String owner) { // Again, just example
        return item.owner.equals(owner);
    }

    public static ItemBuilder builder() {
        return new ItemBuilder();
    }

}
```

Which is commonly used in Guava such as ImmutableSet.builder().

For my case (an utility package), which method of exposing the builder is better?

Comment: Create a factory that resolves the builder from your DI container.

Answer (score 1):

**I think that putting the builder inside the `Item` class itself is a bad design decision regardless of the possible complicated logic.**

It is definitely violating the SRP (Single Responsible Principle). If we would follow such approach, then we will put everything even indirectly related to the Item class to the class itself strongly restricting any further extensibility.

Comment: What if the builder is put inside the same package as Item, but not an inner class of Item class?

Comment: That would be good solution. Item is not responsible for the specific algorithm of creating the instance and you can still be flaxible.